# AutoMapper - How to map collection to dictionary?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-6.0

I have a database table which contains the columns id, parameter id, language and value.
Here is an example for how this table looks like:

| id | parameter id | language | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | de | rot |
| 1 | 2 | de | grün |
| 1 | 3 | de | blau |
| 1 | 1 | en | red |
| 1 | 2 | en | green |
| 1 | 3 | en | blue |
| 2 | 4 | de | klein |
| 2 | 5 | de | mittel |
| 2 | 6 | de | groß |
| 2 | 4 | en | small |
| 2 | 5 | en | medium |
| 2 | 6 | en | large |

I am using EF Core 6 and the generated (scaffolded) class for this table looks like this (navigation properties are left out here for simplicity):

```
public partial class TblParameters
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use AutoMapper to map an `ICollection<TblParameters>` into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>`. The reason for this is that I can then easily use the language as key to get the available parameters/options for that language.
The `ICollection<TblParameters>` only contains entries with the same `id`.
The mapped dictionary should look like this:

```
["de", {[1, "rot"], [2, "grün"], [3, "blau"]}]
["en", {[1, "red"], [2, "green"], [3, "blue"]}]
```

My first attempt so far was to create a new map like this but I have no idea what to write inside the `ConstructUsing` call:

```
CreateMap<ICollection<TblRecipePartParameter>, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, string>>>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => ...);
```

Is this even the right approach? If not, how can I create a mapping for this in AutoMapper?

Comment: Try LINQ, `GroupBy` followed by `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Sounds like a good idea but do you have an example? I don't know what to do after calling `GroupBy` to get the individual properties like `ParameterId` and `Value` from the group and put them into the dictionary.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Nevermind, I got it to work now like this: `.GroupBy(x => x.Language).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToDictionary(x => x.ParameterId, x => x.Value))`

Comment: Hi @Chris, good to see you found the answer. Suggest writing it as the answer post. You may refer to [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)